# An error occurred trying to create a scatter plot using "bokeh.io"

Tags: python

This is my code. type of data is pandas.Data
I want to return scatter plot.
Hope someone could help!!
The x-coordinate contains part of the key value of the pandas.
The y-coordinate contains the value of the price column of the pandas.
I don't know how to write it when I have to write it with these two scatter plots.
data set type is pandas.Database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDft9.png)

```
def scatter_feature(data, feature_name):
    """
    This function returns a scatter plot for the particular `feature_name` v Price
    `data` should be a `DataFrame`
    `feature_name` should be a string
    """
    scatter = Scatter(data, x= feature_name, y='Price', 
xlabel=feature_name,ylabel='Price')
    
    output_file('scatter.html')
    
    return scatter
    
show(scatter_feature(data,'Mileage'))
show(scatter_feature(data,'Year'))



AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-97dc81ee03de> in <module>()
     11     return scatter
     12 
---> 13 show(scatter_feature(data,'Mileage'))
     14 show(scatter_feature(data,'Year'))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/io.py in show(obj, browser, new, notebook_handle)
    297     '''
    298     if obj not in _state.document.roots:
--> 299         _state.document.add_root(obj)
    300     return _show_with_state(obj, _state, browser, new, notebook_handle=notebook_handle)
    301 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/document.py in add_root(self, model, setter)
    526             self._roots.append(model)
    527         finally:
--> 528             self._pop_all_models_freeze()
    529         self._trigger_on_change(RootAddedEvent(self, model, setter))
    530 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/document.py in _pop_all_models_freeze(self)
    383         self._all_models_freeze_count -= 1
    384         if self._all_models_freeze_count == 0:
--> 385             self._recompute_all_models()
    386 
    387     def _invalidate_all_models(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bokeh/document.py in _recompute_all_models(self)
    393         new_all_models_set = set()
    394         for r in self.roots:
--> 395             new_all_models_set = new_all_models_set.union(r.references())
    396         old_all_models_set = set(self._all_models.values())
    397         to_detach = old_all_models_set - new_all_models_set

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'references'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below come directly from the [doumentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html?highlight=scatter#bokeh.plotting.Figure.scatter). In bokeh you have to define a `figure` first and then you can call the `scatter` function.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

p = figure(plot_width=300, plot_height=300)
p.scatter([1,2,3],[4,5,6], marker="square", fill_color="red")
# p.scatter("data1", "data2", marker="mtype", source=data_source, ...)
show(p)
```

I hope yu can adapt this solution to your problem.